# How to remove the top panel in PhpStorm 2023?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

How to remove the top panel in PhpStorm 2023? Is it possible? I need this when I work on small laptops to get whole height of a display.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's possible only if you manually remove all the items from the toolbar in IDE *Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and toolbars*.

There's a request to allow hiding the toolbar in the new UI, please upvote [IDEA-303413](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303413/Allow-hiding-the-main-toolbar-in-normal-view-mode).